# Projective dimension of cohomology over regular rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a regular ring and $F^{\bullet}: 0\to F^0 \to F^1 \to \dots \to F^d \to 0$ is a complex of finite rank free $R$-modules.  Is is true that $\mathrm{projdim}H^i(F^{\bullet}) \leq d$ for all $i$?

Answer (score 1):

No if $R$ has dimension $>1$. Take a finitely presented module $M$ of projective dimension $>1$. Choose a finite presentation of $M$, i.e. a complex $0\rightarrow F^0\rightarrow F^1\rightarrow 0$ as in your question with $H^1(F^\bullet)=M$. Then you get a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is false in an embarrassingly obvious way, let me point out my motivation for asking.  Suppose $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a local Cohen-Macaulay ring and $F^{\bullet}$ is as in the question.  Then one can show that every minimal prime in the $R$-support of $H^{\ast}(F^{\bullet})$ has height $\leq d$.   This would follow from the stronger but false statement which I queried.  In the situation of Fernando Muro's counterexample, this theorem says that if $R^{m}\overset{f}{\to } R^{n} \to M \to 0$ is a presentation, then $M$ and $\ker{f}$ can't both have dimension $ <d-1$.